# v-select on close event or remove validation error timer?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

**Final Edit/Solution:** https://jsfiddle.net/up9xkhsm/1/

Is there such an event for v-select that I can key on when it is closed? Or some sort of a 'timer' I can set to remove validation errors after they occur?

This is the `v-select` I am using:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects

Edit: this outlines the issue: 
https://jsfiddle.net/96vnLm7g/

I want to know when a user clicked on the `v-select` but did not select anything. It has to be possible, obviously, since the validation can pick up on this..

Comment: What about using @input="inputChanged()" event because as soon as some value is selected select is automatically closed.And do your work in inputChanged method.

Comment: If you click on the v-select, ***but do not select anything and then click off of it*** that event is not fired, as the Fiddle demonstrates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `onChange` prop to add your callback function, so you can check for the `v-model` assigned to `v-select` if has changed, to clear the validation errors. Or watch the `v-model` assigned to `v-select` for changes.

Using `onChange`:

```
  <v-select :options="options" :on-change="cleanUpValidation" v-model="selectModel" name="some-select"></v-select>
```

And in VueJS

```
methods: {
    cleanUpValidation(){
     //do the cleanup
    }
  }
```

By default, onChange emits `input` event with value of selected option:

```
default: function (val) {
        this.$emit('input', val)
    }
```

So you can use it also to catch the input event:

```
  <v-select :options="options" @input="cleanUpValidation" v-model="selectModel" name="some-select"></v-select>
```

In VueJS

```
 methods: {
    cleanUpValidation(val){
      //do something with selected option value or cleanup error
    }
  }
```

Or you can watch the model assigned to `v-select`:

```
watch: {
    'selectModel' : function(){
      //do the cleanup or something with this.selectModel
    }
  }
```

For onChange and other props see: 
https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Api/Props.html

Same thing would apply for VuetifyJS's v-select.

Edit: 
Main goal was to clear validation errors when v-select is actually clicked.
v-select uses focus event within its onClick() method, to tell the VueJS that component is clicked, so that can be used to catch the click event:

```
      <v-select
        @input="inputChanged"
        v-on:change="changeChanged"
        label="Select Item"
        :items="myItems"
        required
        :rules="rules.requiredField"
        @focus="focusChanged"
      >
      </v-select>
```

And in js:

```
   methods:{
    focusChanged(){
        console.log('focusChanged ');
    },
   }
```

For last example: https://jsfiddle.net/c5moqweu/

And see https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.js

```
onClick
```

Method

Comment: I am also using the native v-select in Vuetify - not the one from Sagalbot. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects

Comment: Here is the issue.. - https://jsfiddle.net/96vnLm7g/ - if you click on select, and then don't select anything, but click outside of the select - how do I key on this event? It must be possible since validation can clearly see I have clicked outside of the v-select, but did not select anything (hence the validation error). I want to be able to clear the validation error after X seconds if the user didn't select anything. As you can see the 'change' or 'input' events are not fired when this occurs.

Comment: @MattOestreich, I have edited my answer. You need to use `@focus`. See my https://jsfiddle.net/c5moqweu/

Comment: Thank you for your help! @niklaz You pointed me in the right direction.  This is what I wound up going with.. https://jsfiddle.net/up9xkhsm/1/